# allowed length for input name attribute

Tags: html, input, name-attribute

I have a PHP script that will generate HTML forms dynamically. This script write text of input label in the name attribute of input.
my problem is that when the name attribute text is too long browser not send that input.
Is there any way to submit these forms correctly?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: whole script files are here: http://gandomy.ir/download/FormBuilder.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every body. My problem solved. I changed `suhosin` setting in my server.
I set these field to 256:

```
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length

suhosin.post.max_name_length
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the maxlength "tag".

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="10" />
```

So now the user can only enter 10 characters.

Comment: thank you but it is not my answer. name of the input is too long(for example more than 50 characters) not input value

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?